Can a graduate of Harvard Extension School apply for a PhD position at any other university in the USA?
My brother is a social science graduate. He wants to have a masters degree in CS and then wants to do a PhD in CS.
Can a graduate of Harvard Extension School apply for a PhD position at any other university in the USA, or is that degree only for getting jobs?

In the US, one can change fields between undergraduate and graduate school. So, earning a CS masters from Harvard Extension is possible. And, as the masters is recognized as a valid degree, it is then possible to apply for doctoral programs in CS as well.
In fact, it is possible to apply for doctoral programs in CS in the US without any masters at all and switching from social science to CS is possible, though not an easy or obvious "admit". It would depend on how much computing background was learned in the bachelors and how much "catchup" work there is in the graduate (doctoral) program.
If the social science degree is from a US university it is probably more possible, since such a degree is broad based. In some other countries an undergraduate degree is more focused making it less likely that much of any CS was included. But all of that is for the admissions committee to decide.
But you can apply, in any case.

Note for completeness that many universities offer evening and part-time masters programs that are valid and recognized, not just Harvard. The programs won't always by described as "Extension" though.
